# How to convert complex json string to object c#

Tags: c#, json

I wanna convert Json String to Object in c#. I tried several times with several codes but its gave me a parsing error. Refer below json.

```
{
"Test Name1": [{
    "scores": [{
        "score": "-0.00",
        "ethnicity": "Asian"
    },
    {
        "score": "0.00",
        "ethnicity": "GreaterAfrican"
    },
    {
        "score": "1.00",
        "ethnicity": "GreaterEuropean"
    }],
    "best": "European"
},
{
    "scores": [{
        "score": "1.00",
        "ethnicity": "British"
    },
    {
        "score": "0.00",
        "ethnicity": "Jewish"
    },
    {
        "score": "-0.00",
        "ethnicity": "WestEuropean"
    },
    {
        "score": "0.00",
        "ethnicity": "EastEuropean"
    }],
    "best": "British"
}],
"Test Name2": [{
    "scores": [{
        "score": "-0.00",
        "ethnicity": "Asian"
    },
    {
        "score": "0.00",
        "ethnicity": "GreaterAfrican"
    },
    {
        "score": "1.00",
        "ethnicity": "GreaterEuropean"
    }],
    "best": "GreaterEuropean"
},
{
    "scores": [{
        "score": "-5.95",
        "ethnicity": "British"
    },
    {
        "score": "6.95",
        "ethnicity": "Jewish"
    },
    {
        "score": "0.00",
        "ethnicity": "WestEuropean"
    },
    {
        "score": "-0.00",
        "ethnicity": "EastEuropean"
    }],
    "best": "Jewish"
}]
```

}

I am trying with below code.

```
var Result = client.PostAsync(APIURL, httpContent).Result;
if(Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
      var responseStr = Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();       
                    dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(responseStr.ToString());                        
  }
```

But unable to convert this to object. How it can be done?

Comment: What's the error message that you receive?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: You must await the async call or you will run the next line before the content is read.

Comment: In *JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>*, "object" shall be replaced with a class whose public variables correspond to the input Json structure. (high level classes may refer to lower level classes).

Comment: Also, if you are doing this in an asp.net context don't use `.Result` on the PostAsync. It can deadlock so just await that as well.

Comment: Another option is to use `Newtonsoft.Json` and `System.CodeDom` to first create your C# type from the JSON string and then use CodeDom to generate your C# type file. You can then replace `<object>` with e.g. `<Score>`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to deserialize a "tostring" representation of a task, rather than the return value of that task.

Try this:

```
if(Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responseStr = await Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();       
    dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(responseStr);                        
}
```